# Basis of meromorphic $1$-forms on compact Riemann surface.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to solve the following exercise but I do not really know how to proceed.

For an integral divisor $D$ and any compact Riemann surface $M$, describe a basis of the space $\Omega(-D)$.

Where $\Omega(-D) = \{\omega\in\mathcal{M}\Omega^1(M)\mid (\omega)\geq -D\}$. Since $D = \sum_v s_vp_v$ is integral i.e. $s_v>0$ for at least one $v$, the elements of $\Omega(-D)$ are meromorphic $1$-forms which have a pole of order at most $s_v$ at $p_v$. This clearly contains all holomorphic differentials and I know how to generate those, but I have no idea about any classification of the strictly meromorphic differentials in terms of their dimension.

I have only seen proven the existence of such differentials with a single pole of higher order, or of differentials with two simple poles in the book of Wilhelm Schlag on *A course in Complex Analysis and Riemann surfaces*.

I also tried finding the dimension using the Riemann-Roch theorem, but for that I would need to find the dimension of $L(-D)$ the meromorphic functions on $M$ which only have poles at $p_v$ of order at most $s_v$. But I am not sure how to formally do this aswell.

Does anyone know how to find this basis $\Omega(-D)$?

Comment: Note that you're using the Riemann-Roch theorem for the divisor $-D$, so you should consider $L(D)$ and not $L(-D)$. What can you say about $L(D)$ if $M$ is compact?

Comment: What kind of meromorphic differentials do you know? Can you construct a differential with a double pole at $p_1$? A triple? A single?

Comment: Suppose $D = p_1 + \cdots + p_5$. How many linearly independent non-holomorphic meromorphic differentials can you construct that lie in $\Omega(-D)$? (Hint: the answer is not $\binom{5}{2} = 10$). What happens when you repeat one point, e.g. $D + p_1$?

Comment: @GillesCastel Not sure what you can say about $L(D)$ if $M$ is compact. I suppose you would need meromorphic functions with  zeros of multiplicity $s_v$ at $p_v$ to generate the whole space, but not sure how to make this rigorous. I am able to construct differentials with a pole of order $\geq 2$ at $p_v$ and nowhere else. But still I would not know whether these generate all the meromorphic differentials I want. Are meromorphic differentials completely characterised by their behaviour at poles or zeros?

Comment: In particular, you need meromorphic functions with no poles (as D is an integral divisor), so you're looking for holomorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface. What can you say about such functions?

Comment: @GillesCastel Well the holomorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ are of dimension $g$. But I think there are less functions in $L(D)$ since we can only allow functions which have a zero at $p_v$ of multiplicity $s_v$ or higher.

Comment: I think you're confusing holomorphic differentials and holomorphic functions here. The dimension of holomorphic differentials is indeed $g$, but the only holomorphic _functions_ from a compact surface are the constant functions. So we find that the dimension of $L(D)$ is 1. Hence Riemann-Roch gives $\dim \Omega(-D) = g + \deg D$. The $g$ comes from the holomorphic differentials, and now you have to find $\deg D$ non-holomorphic meromorphic differentials.

Comment: @GillesCastel To answer your third comment, I think the answer is $4+3+2+1$ since we cannot have a single simple pole, so we can only have differentials with two poles. Repeating a point we can also get a meromorphic differential with which has a double pole at that point. But can there be only one linearly independent meromorphic differential if we fix the poles?

Comment: Suppose you have two meromorphic differentials with have the same singular behaviour at a point (and are only singular at that specific point for example) Subtracting them removes the pole, so you're left with a holomorphic differential, which is already in your basis.

Comment: @GillesCastel Aah, thank you. That makes sense. I will think some more on this, but you have helped me a lot :) I guess I find the concept of a differential a bit confusing since it is often treated just like a function.

Comment: In a previous comment, said that dimension of $L(D) = 1$, but that isn't true if $D$ is not trivial. We get that the dimension is $0$, because the only holomorphic functions having zeros at points in $D$ is the constant function $0$. So my formula for $\dim \Omega(-D)$ was off by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riemann-Roch tells us that
$$
    L(D) = \deg(-D) - g + 1 + \dim \Omega(-D)
.$$ 
If  $M$ is compact and if $D \ge 0$ is not trivial, we have $L(D) = \{0\}$, so dimension is $0$.
Indeed, $L(D)$ contains holomorphic functions, and the only holomorphic functions from a compact Riemann surfaces are constant functions. However if $D$ is not trivial, it forces us to have a zero somewhere. Hence the function is constant $0$.

Using $\deg(-D) = - \deg (D)$, we have
$$
    \dim \Omega(-D) = g + \deg(D) - 1
.$$ 
As you've guessed, the $g$ comes from the dimension of holomorphic differentials on the surface. We are set out to find $\deg D - 1$ non-holomorphic meromorphic differentials which form a basis for $\Omega(-D)$.

Write $ D = \sum n_i p_i$, where the $p_i$ are $N$ distinct points and  $n_i \ge 0$. Then $\Omega(-D)$ contains meromorphic differentials which have poles $p_i$ of order at most $n_i$.
There are two types of meromorphic differentials we can construct:

- Denote with $\tau_{p_i, k}$ a meromorphic differential with pole of order $k\ge 2$ at $p_i$
- Denote with $\omega_{p_i, p_j}$ a meromorphic differential with simple poles at $p_i$ and $p_j$ and residues $1$ and $-1$.

We also know there is a basis of $g$ holomorphic forms, so

- Denote with $\alpha_i$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, g\}$ a basis for holomorphic one forms.

Then we claim the following is a  basis for $ \Omega(-D)$:

$$
\{ \tau_{p_i, k_{i,j}} \mid 2 \le  k_{i,j} \le n_i \} 
\cup 
\{
\omega_{p_1, p_2},
\omega_{p_2, p_3},
\ldots,
\omega_{p_{N-1}, p_N}
\} 
\cup \{\alpha_i  \mid 1 \le i \le g\} 
.$$

So in total, the dimension is indeed $\deg(D) + g - 1$.

As an example, consider $D = 3 p_1 + 1 p_2 + 1 p_3 + 2 p_4 + 4p_5$.

[image]

How many differentials of the $\tau$-type can we construct? Only at points which occur multiple times. So we get the following, where I omitted the reference to the point in the notation for $\tau$, an only included the degree of the pole.

[image]

Now, couldn't  there be other meromorphic differentials we need to include in our basis which have the same singular behavior? Well, suppose $\tau$ and $\tau'$ have the same singular behaviour at a point. Then $\tau - \tau'$ is a holomorphic differential, which is already in our basis. So $\tau'$ is not independent.

What about the differentials of type $\omega$? You'd think we would need to include $\omega_{p_i, p_j}$ for all possible pairs. But this is not the case. For example $\omega_{p_1, p_3}$ is a linear combination of $\omega_{p_1, p_2} + \omega_{p_2, p_3}$ and some holomorphic differentials, by the same reasoning as above. So we only need to include adjacent pairs: $\omega_{p_1, p_2}, ... \omega_{p_{N-1}, p_N}$. Note that we don't even need to include the pair $\omega_{p_N, p_1}$. This way we end up with the following:

[image]

Here an $\omega$ on a line denotes the differential form with poles at the endpoints. This makes it clear that the dimension is $g + \deg D - 1$.

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear. In the case that D is trivial. We are in the case of only holomorphic differentials, so the dimension is $g$ which corresponds to what we find from Riemann-Roch.